# Onclick listener not recognizing right image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, listener, onclicklistener

I have a OnClicklistener set to a image:

```
                    iv_album[i] = new ImageView(main.this);
                    iv_album[i].setImageBitmap(resized_a_p);
                    iv_album[i].setPadding(width-resized_a_p.getHeight()-5, t_img, 5, 0);
                    iv_album[i].setId(i);                   
                    iv_album[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                System.out.println(v.getId());
                                }
                          });
```

And it always fires an id on the console when i click above, left of, or on the image. But not when i click below !!

Anyone knows why this happens ? 
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeriK.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it could be an issue with this line -

```
iv_album[i].setPadding(width-resized_a_p.getHeight()-5, t_img, 5, 0);
```

`OnClickListener`s will work with the padded portions.

Comment: I'm not sure what your target is. So, can't tell much. All I can say is that OnClickListener for a view works with the area covered by the actual dimensions + padding.

Comment: Ok, so my app will create imageviews on the right, and display them one below the other.
I need to use: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, iv_album[i-1].getId()); ?

cause that isn't working, they align correct to the right side, but won't appear below each other